# A logo looking like the image in description

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw

[image]

How can i make a logo filled with other shape like the example i have given

I have already used "CIRCLEFILL" plugin in illustrator but that was not as clear as unilever logo is.

Please suggest is there another plugin or script for illustrator or i have to do that manually.

Comment: Hi! There's still logos that are entirely made "manually" and some guy spent hours adjusting each shape in the logo. It's possible you won't find a one-click solution that gives such a perfect result and you'll need to adjust each shape manually too to get that organic feel!

Answer (score 0):

Create a mask of the shape required, then create a Clipping Mask, inserting your images inside the shape. Then manually adjust as previously mentioned.